# Can I validate that a prop has a particular shape?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In React, I can give the following `propTypes`:

`user: PropTypes.shape({
  username: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired
})`

This verifies that the passed `user` prop includes both `username` and `email` properties of type `String`.

Is there a way to do something similar in Vue for plain objects? That is, without requiring a constructor function to create the objects, e.g. `new User()`.

Answer (score -1):

In your component `prop` property, declare your `user` property of type `Object`

```
props: {
  user: {
    type: Object,
    default: {}
  }
}
```

Then your component template should have something like this

```
<my-component 
  :user="{ 
    username: 'Chris', 
    email: 'something@email.com' 
  }"
></my-component>
```

Comment: That does not provide the kind of validation the OP asked for, though. Cue does not offer that. While you can add a validate function to the prop, the validation is left to the dev, probably using a third party lib.

Comment: Yep. I realized after answering. IMHO that's an utility function, not meant to be handled by a framework like Vue.